# Comprehensive documentation of wpa_supplicant.conf with description of all parameters and default values

Tags: documentation, wpa-supplicant

I there any up to date, comprehensive documentation of `wpa_supplicant` which describes all possible parameters of `wpa_supplicant.conf` and it's default values.

The man page of `wpa_supplicant.conf` gives only examples same for every other resources I found on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found it on the official homepage:

http://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf